# Serialize XML element having property named value using Jackson

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jackson, jaxb, jackson2

I'm trying to deserialize/serialize xml content with below element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<confirmationConditions>
    <condition type="NM-GD" value="something">no modification of guest details</condition>
</confirmationConditions>
```

How can I properly create java beans with jackson annotations to parse this correctly. I've tried with JAXB annotations and jackson fails saying it can't be having to `value` fields. With below java beans I got following error.

```
public class Condition
{
    @JacksonXmlProperty( isAttribute = true, localName = "type" )
    private String type;
    @JacksonXmlProperty( isAttribute = true, localName = "value" )
    private String value;
    private String text;
}
```

Error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "" (class Condition), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "value", "type", "text"])
 at [Source: (File); line: 3, column: 73] (through reference chain: ConfirmationConditions["condition"]->Condition[""])
```

Basically what I want is to map element content to `text` field. I have no control over xml so changing it would not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you need here is to add @JacksonXmlText

```
class Condition {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String type;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String value;
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String text;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

And parse it this way:

```
    JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
    module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(module);

    xmlMapper.readValue(
            "<condition type=\"NM-GD\" value=\"something\">no modification of guest details</condition>", Condition.class);
```